# Unable to settle out packages needed for virtualization on Ubuntu 18.04.02

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I want to install the dependencies for managing VMs on an `Ubuntu 18.04.02` machine.

So I did:

```
# apt install -y libvirt* qemu*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libvirt-clients' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-sanlock' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-wireshark' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-glib-1.0-dev' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirtodbc0' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirtuoso5.5-cil' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-bin' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-dev' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-doc' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-zfs' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-ocaml-dev-5cb27:i386' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-daemon-system' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-dbus' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-ocaml-dev-oxgx1' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-sheepdog' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-glib-1.0-0' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-ocaml' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt0' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-ocaml-5cb27:i386' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-ocaml-oxgx1' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-sandbox-1.0-dev' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-ocaml-dev' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-gluster' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-sandbox-1.0-5' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-daemon' for glob 'libvirt*'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-ocaml' instead of 'libvirt-ocaml-oxgx1'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-ocaml-dev' instead of 'libvirt-ocaml-dev-oxgx1'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-ocaml:i386' instead of 'libvirt-ocaml-5cb27:i386'
Note, selecting 'libvirt-ocaml-dev:i386' instead of 'libvirt-ocaml-dev-5cb27:i386'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-ppcemb' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-m68k' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-tricore' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-kvm-extras' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-x86-64' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-i386' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-keymaps' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-mips' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-ppc' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-ppc64' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-microblazeel' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-cris' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-sh4' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-microblaze' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-x86' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-s390x' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-kvm-extras-static' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-user' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemubuilder' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-sparc64' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-mips64' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-alpha' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-mipsel' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-lm32' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-aarch64' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-xtensaeb' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-moxie' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-nios2' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-user-static' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-utils' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-efi' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-sparc' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-launcher' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-user-binfmt' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-or1k' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-kvm' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-efi-arm' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-unicore32' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-efi-aarch64' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-guest-agent' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemuctl' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-slof' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-arm' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-xtensa' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-mips64el' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-block-extra' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-common' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-sh4eb' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system' for glob 'qemu*'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-arm' instead of 'qemu-system-aarch64'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-common' instead of 'qemu-keymaps'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-ppc' instead of 'qemu-system-ppc64'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-ppc' instead of 'qemu-system-ppcemb'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-x86' instead of 'qemu-system-i386'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-x86' instead of 'qemu-system-x86-64'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-mips' instead of 'qemu-system-mips64'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-mips' instead of 'qemu-system-mips64el'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-mips' instead of 'qemu-system-mipsel'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-alpha'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-cris'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-lm32'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-m68k'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-microblaze'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-microblazeel'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-moxie'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-nios2'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-or1k'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-sh4'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-sh4eb'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-tricore'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-unicore32'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-xtensa'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-misc' instead of 'qemu-system-xtensaeb'
Note, selecting 'qemu-system-sparc' instead of 'qemu-system-sparc64'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libvirt-ocaml : Depends: ocaml-base-nox-4.05.0
                 Conflicts: libvirt-ocaml:i386 but 0.6.1.4-2build1 is to be installed
 libvirt-ocaml:i386 : Conflicts: libvirt-ocaml but 0.6.1.4-2build1 is to be installed
 libvirt-ocaml-dev : Depends: ocaml-findlib but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0
                     Conflicts: libvirt-ocaml-dev:i386 but 0.6.1.4-2build1 is to be installed
 libvirt-ocaml-dev:i386 : Depends: ocaml-nox-4.05.0:i386
                          Conflicts: libvirt-ocaml-dev but 0.6.1.4-2build1 is to be installed
 qemu-user-binfmt : Conflicts: qemu-user-static
                    Conflicts: qemu-user-static:i386
 qemu-user-static : Conflicts: qemu-user-binfmt
                    Conflicts: qemu-user-binfmt:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I even tried to remove any existing packages by:

```
# apt remove -y libvirt* qemu*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

How can I address this dependency mayhem?

Comment: The is architecture problem! You have selected all packages even i386. However your architecture is x86_64. All that you need is to install this this packages `qemu, qemu-kvm, libvirt-bin` and possibly `virt-manager`. On my testing machines I select to install `virt-manager` only and it installs all needed dependencies: qemu, libvirt.

Comment: doesn't apt recognize the system's architecture and handle dependencies accordingly?